# Darken an image using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div with an image background:

```
<div class="image-cover" style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + item.image + ')' }}>
      <div className="name">{item.name}</div>
</div>
```

(the is React code, but essentially the above div has the image applied as a background.)

I want to darken the image, possibly as a gradient so that only the bottom is dark, and fades up to normal. Almost everywhere I searched mentions adding the image as a reference in the CSS. However, in my case, the image url is known only at runtime and is applied in the html.

How can I darken my div here?

Comment: Is drawing a div over the top an option?

Comment: [CSS3 filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) are an option, but don't have the option for gradients.  If that's what you need, I think @texelate is on the right track.

Comment: @texelate sure that's an option...

Comment: Sass is really good for things like this. They have built in functions that can help you darken an image. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve that effect by using `linear-gradient` background on the `div`'s `::before` pseudo-element. The idea is to cover the `div` with its `::before` pseudo-element (or with another `div`, but pseudo-elements don't add any extra elements), and then applying a gradient background to the pseudo-elemetn:

```
.image-cover {
    position: relative;
}

.image-cover::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* Adjust the color values to achieve desired darkness */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/e0zf7oey/) to show it in action.

Comment: Do you think you could help me with one more thing? What if I also wanted a darkening at the top of the image? So dark at the top and bottom.

Comment: @Prabhu if that's the case, you can add an extra color at the end of the `linear-gradient` parameters, like for example: `linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75))` would created a sort of darkening at the top and bottom, then somewhat lighter in the middle.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply combine an image and a gradient, like this

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(black,
                    transparent 20%,
                    transparent 80%,
                    black),
    url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/1/);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Or use a pseudo element, like this

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/1/);
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Inset Box-Shadow

**Advantage:** slim on code, no additional pseudoelement needed

**Disadvantage:** Box shadow **size and offset values** can for current w3 standard be **ONLY absolute** (not percentual), therefore dynamic/various size of the shadowed element cannot be solved without JavaScript calculating elements dimensions.

**There are better answers, so i am just going to throw this as an additional option (worse).**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background:url(http://unsplash.it/200/200);
  width:200px;
  height:200px;      
}

.darkened{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -200px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="darkened"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements can have multiple backgrounds, and you want to set it from code?

```js
let imageURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqkeF.png"; // an example image
let cssURL = "url( "  + imageURL + ")"; // convert to CSS url declaration
let gradient = "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0))";
divElement.style.backgroundImage = gradient + "," + cssURL;
```

```html
<div id="divElement" style="height:128px; width: 256px;">
    #divElement
</div>
```

,

Essentially convert the image URL known at run time into a CSS url declaration, create a CSS gradient pattern of your choosing and add them as a comma separated list to the `backgroundImage` property of the element's style attribute.

I used the global variable `divElement` for testing - use `document.getElementById` as you wish.

Edit: looking at your code, it should be fairly easy to put the background image list in the template: the stand-alone code above was written to check it worked :-)